# Mapping a nested `BehaviorSubject` object to a flat array in RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, flatten, behaviorsubject

I have a `BehaviorSubject` emitting a collection of `Parent` objects and each parent has a property `children` that is another `BehaviorSubject` emitting a collection of `Child` objects.
Now I want to map this data to a new behavior subject that resolves to an array holding parents and children in their respective order.

In case any parent or child collection emits a new collection value the resulting behavior subject should emit the new values for the `Parent`/`Child` array.

I managed to do it in the end like this:

Setting up the data model:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

class Child {
  constructor(public name: string) {
  }
}

class Parent {
  constructor(public children: BehaviorSubject<Child[]>) {
  }
}

const children1 = new BehaviorSubject([
  new Child('john'),
  new Child('may'),
  new Child('betty'),
]);
const children2 = new BehaviorSubject([
  new Child('key'),
  new Child('tom'),
]);
const children3 = new BehaviorSubject([
  new Child('jane'),
]);

const parent1 = new Parent(children1);
const parent2 = new Parent(children2);
const parent3 = new Parent(children3);

const collection = new BehaviorSubject([
  parent1,
  parent2,
]);
```

Mapping the collection to the desired result:

```
const result = collection.pipe(
  switchMap((parents: Parent[]) => {
    const array = parents.reduce(
      (accumulator: Array<Observable<Parent|Child[]>>, current: Parent) => {
        accumulator.push(of(current), current.children)
        return accumulator;
      },
      [],
    );
    return combineLatest(array).pipe(
      map((result: Array<Parent|Child[]>) => result.flat()),
    );
  }),
);

result.subscribe((result: any) => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

It emits nicely when changing parent and/or children collections.

```
collection.next([parent1, parent2, parent3]);
children3.next([
  new Child('john'),
  new Child('may'),
  new Child('betty'),
  new Child('marcus'),
]);
```

Is there a more proper RxJS solutions for these things in the code above:

1. currently I used array reduce; I tried with reduce operator from RxJS, but it doesn't work, most likely because the source Observable never completes. Is there a way to tackle this?
2. flattening the result with: `map((result: Array<Parent|Child[]>) => result.flat())`. Somehow I expect there to be a simpler way to just flatten the result to a one dimensional array.

Still learning RxJS, so other suggestions are welcome.

**[A StackBlitz with the above code can be found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rx-playground-p7vh1m)**

So the result will be a mixed array. So for example when having 2 parents, with the first one 3 children and second 2 children, the result would be: `[Parent, Child, Child, Child, Parent, Child, Child]`.

Comment: Do you want a heterogeneous array as the result?

Comment: @Asti yes, exactly. For example I have two Parents, one with two children and one with three, then the result should look like: `[Parent, Child, Child, Child, Parent, Child, Child]`.